# Query a list where no values are returned

Tags: c#, linq

```
IEnumerable<ATable> stuff = 
        _aTableRepository.Entity.ByTitle(TITLE).ByDocTypeCode(Id).ToList();
```

The above returns a list of items

```
decimal? xyz = stuff.Where(x => x.CLAUSE == "test").FirstOrDefault().Id ?? 0;
```

Now I want to query the list and get the id, which is a decimal type. However, there are no clauses that equal "test" and this line bombs out. It seems like if nothing is found, that the nullable decimal would get set to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query, is that `FirstOrDefault` will return default entity value if there is no matching entities. I believe entity is a reference type in your application, so you have `null` as default value. Trying to get `Id` of `null` gives you `NullReferenceException`.

Project sequence of entities to sequence of ids and select first one or use default value:

```
decimal? xyz = stuff.Where(x => x.CLAUSE == "test")
                    .Select(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault() ?? 0;
```

You can also use [`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb355419(v=vs.100).aspx) to provide default value:

```
decimal? xyz = stuff.Where(x => x.CLAUSE == "test")
                    .Select(x => x.Id)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(0).First();
```

And old school approach - simply get first matching entity and check if its not null:

```
var testEntity = stuff.FirstOrDefault(x => x.CLAUSE == "test");
decimal? xyz = testEntity == null ? 0 : testEntity.Id;
```